# What does a Terracotta server do when it is used as a backend for EHCache with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache, distributed-caching, terracotta

My DAL is implemented with `Hibernate` and I want to use `EHCache` as its second level cache with its distributed capabilities (for scalability and HA).
Seeing as `EHCache` provides distributed caching only with `Terracotta` my question is what is the role of the `Terracotta` server instance? Does it also hold data? Does it only coordinate the distribution between the partitioned cache parts?
My confusion derives mainly from [this](http://www.terracotta.org/documentation/3.1.x/product-documentation-15.html) explanation regarding TSA which says the server holds the data but I think that maybe in my scenario the cache and the `Terracotta` server are sort of merged. Am I correct?
If the server does hold data then why shouldn't the bottleneck just move from the db to the `Terracotta` server?

**Update:**
Affe's answer answered the second part of my question which was the important part but just in case someone comes by looking for the first part I'll say that the TC server has to hold all the data that the EHCache in memory holds and so if you want a distributed cache (not replicated) then the L2 (TC server) must hold all the objects itself as well.

Thanks in advance,
Ittai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is it's still significantly faster to contact the terracotta cluster via the terracotta driver and do what's basically a Map lookup, than to acquire a database connection and execute an SQL statement.  Even if that does become the application's choke point, overall throughput would be expected to still be significantly higher than a JDBC Connection + SQL choke point.  Open connections and open cursors are big resource hogs in the database, an open socket to the terracotta cluster is not!

Comment: I understand the question as - why EHCache needs terracotta, while for example JBoss cache is decentralized, and does not need any additional server

Comment: That was not the question actually but It's a nice addendum.

Comment: I guess we're not clear on which of your ? statements are rhetorical and what the actual question is?  'Yes' you understand it, the terracotta solution uses an external server cluster.  I tried to focus on the last actual question of why would you bother doing such a thing.

Answer (score 3):

You can get ehcache clustered without using terracotta. They have documentation for doing it via RMI, JGroups and JMS. We are using JMS since we have a significant JMS infrastructure to handle the communication already. I don't know how well it will scale in the long term, but our current concern is just HA.

Comment: Thanks Matt.Indeed without Terracotta you can get replication and not distribution which doesn't seem to fit my needs with regards to scalability.

Comment: eh can serve as an object cache just fine with those types of replication methods, however, it does not support the older Hibernate SPI for locking when used that way.  Specifically as a Hibernate L2 cache you have to be very careful, as Hibernate will be issuing lock commands that eh is simply ignoring.  (behavior depends on specific versions of both)